# How to do filter the event in mouse move event

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

Here in my sample program i want to use mouse move event here i got x,y position but i want to filtered the event only on right click and know the mouse release event position in mouse move event.Can any one please help me how to find to out this position.
Given below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
ax.set_title('Click on the colorbar')

highlight = ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_all_like(data), interpolation='nearest',
                      vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

def on_pick(cbar,event):
    #here i need to filter the event..right click
    if event.inaxes is cbar.ax:
        print event.xdata,event.ydata,"moveeeeeeeee"

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',partial(on_pick, cbar))

plt.show()
```

Comment: here how can i filtered the event[when i  press the right button only i want to show the x,y positions for that here i mentioned if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove: its showing attribute error can any one please tell me how to filter the event

Comment: So, do I understand you right, do you only want something to happen in the case of a right click release or do you want something to happen both when the mouse is moved and clicked?

Comment: here i need to filter the mouse events when i press the right button only  i  want to display x,y position in mouse move events

Comment: at least pleas tell me when i click right click release i want to do something

Comment: I suppose you want a `'button_release_event'`. The [event handling guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) has some examples.

Comment: i read this page but i want  event filtering

Comment: A motion_notify_event does not contain any information about the button that is used, because mouse movement is independent of any button. Hence you cannot filter anything that isn't there. Instead you need the `'button_release_event'`.

Comment: oh k .thank you so much for this information